# Stop drag event when reaching the min or max

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I stop dragging as soon as the `drag` hits top and bottom of the `.parent`?

As you can see the `.button` is stops as soon as it hits the inner top and bottom of the `.parent` but the event still continuing! . to test it try to drag the `.button` to the bottom ot top and do not stop dragging when reaching the end, as you can see the `new_top` still updating!

```js
$(function() {
    $('.button').mousedown(function(e) {
        if(e.which===1) {
            var button = $(this);
            var parent_height = button.parent().innerHeight();
            var top = parseInt(button.css('top')); //current top position
            var original_ypos = button.css('top','').position().top; //original ypos (without top)
            button.css({top:top+'px'}); //restore top pos
            var drag_min_ypos = 0-original_ypos;
            var drag_max_ypos = parent_height-original_ypos-button.outerHeight();
            var drag_start_ypos = e.clientY;
            $('#log1').text('mousedown top: '+top+', original_ypos: '+original_ypos);
            $(window).on('mousemove',function(e) {
                button.addClass('drag');
                var new_top = top+(e.clientY-drag_start_ypos);
                button.css({top:new_top+'px'});
                if(new_top<drag_min_ypos) { button.css({top:drag_min_ypos+'px'}); }
                if(new_top>drag_max_ypos) { button.css({top:drag_max_ypos+'px'}); }
                $('#log2').text('mousemove min: '+drag_min_ypos+', max: '+drag_max_ypos+', new_top: '+new_top);

            });
            $(window).on('mouseup',function(e) {
                 if(e.which===1) {
                    $('.button').removeClass('drag');
                    $(window).off('mouseup mousemove');
                    $('#log1').text('mouseup');
                    $('#log2').text('');
                 }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px;
    width:45px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    height: 25px;
    clear: both;
}
.button.drag { z-index: 99; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <button id="button1" class="button">Drag</button>

</div>
<div id="log1"></div>
<div id="log2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this line inside your check:

```
$(this).off('mousemove');
```

Which removes the `mousemove` listener when you hit the max y position.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.button').mousedown(function(e) {
        if(e.which===1) {
            var button = $(this);
            var parent_height = button.parent().innerHeight();
            var top = parseInt(button.css('top')); //current top position
            var original_ypos = button.css('top','').position().top; //original ypos (without top)
            button.css({top:top+'px'}); //restore top pos
            var drag_min_ypos = 0-original_ypos;
            var drag_max_ypos = parent_height-original_ypos-button.outerHeight();
            var drag_start_ypos = e.clientY;
            $('#log1').text('mousedown top: '+top+', original_ypos: '+original_ypos);
            $(window).on('mousemove',function(e) {
                button.addClass('drag');
                var new_top = top+(e.clientY-drag_start_ypos);
                button.css({top:new_top+'px'});
                
                if(new_top < drag_min_ypos) {  
                  button.css({top:drag_min_ypos+'px'}); 
                }
                
                if (new_top > drag_max_ypos) {
                  button.css({top:drag_max_ypos+'px'}); 
                  $(this).off('mousemove');   /// <<< ------ HERE
                }
                $('#log2').text('mousemove min: '+drag_min_ypos+', max: '+drag_max_ypos+', new_top: '+new_top);

             
            });
            $(window).on('mouseup',function(e) {
                 if(e.which===1) {
                    $('.button').removeClass('drag');
                    $(window).off('mouseup mousemove');
                    $('#log1').text('mouseup');
                    $('#log2').text('');
                 }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px;
    width:45px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    height: 25px;
    clear: both;
}
.button.drag { z-index: 99; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <button id="button1" class="button">Drag</button>

</div>
<div id="log1"></div>
<div id="log2"></div>
```